# Weird android exception on a HttpPost?

Tags: android, http, exception, post

When I want to access to my server and update my database, Android gives me a weird exception:

```
06-20 17:30:52.715: INFO/Exception3(32256):  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php">
```

Thx!

Comment: it's not an error since it's printed as info. You can ignore it. Is there something that does not work?

Comment: Yes, I thank it was this error. It should be my sql request...

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` outside of the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file.